# firebase cloud function how to call cleanup function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have notifications tokens in db, more than 10k, and I want to send data msg like this:

```
const promises = [];

      l = niz.length;
      for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        promises.push(admin.messaging().sendToDevice(niz[i], payload, options));
      }

      return Promise.all(promises);
```

in niz I have arrays of tokens, length of 999. How from this code to call cleanup function, which will delete tokens which are invalid. I need response and niz[i] to send to cleanup function. But I don't know how because I am sending with promises more than one ...

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there was any error for each message.

```js
    const promises = [];

    l = niz.length;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        promises.push(admin.messaging().sendToDevice(niz[i], payload, options));
    }

    return Promise.all(promises).then((response) => {
        // For each message check if there was an error.
        const tokensToRemove = [];
        response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
            const error = result.error;
            if (error) {
                console.error('Failure sending notification to', tokens[index], error);
                // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
                if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
                    error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
                    // Remove Token : tokens[index]
                }
            }
        });
        return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);
    });
```

You can find complete solution at [FCM Send Notification](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/6c089b18127a74bd2d63ff126b3a1e4b8ada7abd/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js#L28-L91)

Comment: I get this error in logs: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at Promise.all.then (/user_code/index.js:158:29)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)